# How to get distinct single column value while fetching data by joining two tables

Tags: laravel

```
$data['establishments2'] = Establishments::Join("establishment_categories",'establishment_categories.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')->where('establishments.city','LIKE',$location)->where('establishments.status',0)->whereIn('establishment_id',array($est_data))->get(array('establishments.*'));
```

this is controller condition.

I have two tables, in table1 i am matching id with table2 and then fetching data from table1, and in table2 i have multiple values of same id in table 1.  i want to get data of table1 values only one time, but as i am hvg multiple data of same id in table2 , data is repeating multiple times, can anyone please tell me how to get data only one time wheater table2 having single value or multiple value of same id... thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by selecting the field name you desired
instead get all field from table establishments

```
$data['establishments2'] = Establishments::Join("establishment_categories",'establishment_categories.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')->where('establishments.city','LIKE',$location)->where('establishments.status',0)->whereIn('establishment_id',array($est_data))->get(array('establishments.*'));
```

you can select specific field from table establishments like

```
 $data['establishments2'] = Establishments::Join("establishment_categories",'establishment_categories.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')->where('establishments.city','LIKE',$location)->where('establishments.status',0)->whereIn('establishment_id',array($est_data))->get('establishments.fieldName');
```

or you can also do

```
$data['establishments2'] = `Establishments::Join("establishment_categories",'establishment_categories.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')->where('establishments.city','LIKE',$location)->where('establishments.status',0)->whereIn('establishment_id',array($est_data))->select('establishments.fieldName')->get();`
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually i have a condition like, if table1 data exists in table2 then only data of table1 should diplsay,   but the problem is if i  have two  datas of same id in table2 , then it is fetching same data  two times  from table1

Comment: For this you can use distinct () method which eliminate all recurring data and displays it only once like select()->distinct()->get();

Comment: $data['establishments2'] = Establishments::Join("establishment_categories",'establishment_categories.establishment_id','=','establishments.id')->where('establishments.city','LIKE',$location)->where('establishments.status',0)->whereIn('establishment_id',array($est_data))->distinct()->get(array('establishments.*'));     I changed my conditon with distinct, please have a look, it still fetching multiple data

Comment: Remove array from get and use just get(‘establishments.*’);

Comment: If i remove array from  get(array('establishments.*')); , then its showing error  as Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given                what i have to do now, please help